# MediatR has not been registered with AutoFac

Tags: c#, autofac, mediatr

I am getting the following exception:

The exception is very straightforward. It says I have not registered the component. I went through the code, to see what I have done wrong. I don't spot anything that's wrong :( Can someone help me identify what I did wrong and how to resolve it?

> Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException
> HResult=0x80131500   Message=The requested service
> 'MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[[MyApp.Features.Auth.SignIn.Requests.SignInRequest, MyApp.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[MyApp.Features.Auth.SignIn.Response.SignInResponse, MyApp.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.   Source=Autofac   StackTrace:    at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
> MyApp.Infrastructure.MediatorModules.MediatorModules.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__2(Type
> t) in
> E:\JJ\MyApp\MyApp.Infrastructure\MediatorModules\MediatorModules.cs:line
> 23    at
> MediatR.ServiceFactoryExtensions.GetInstance[T](ServiceFactory
> factory)    at
> MediatR.Wrappers.HandlerBase.GetHandler[THandler](ServiceFactory
> factory)

Code

```
public class MyMediatorModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<Mediator>()
                .As<IMediator>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(context =>
            {
                var c = context.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
                return t => c.Resolve(t);
            });

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MyMediatorModule ).Assembly)
                .Where(t => t.Namespace.Contains("MyApp.Features"))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();
        }
}
```

**Startup**

```
builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());
builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder =>
{
    builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(typeof(MyMediatorModule).Assembly);

    builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(typeof(Program).Assembly);

});
```

**RequestHandler**

```
public class SignInRequestHandler : RequestHandler<SignInRequest, SignInResponse>
{

    public SignInRequestHandler(DataContext dataContext) : base(dataContext)
    {
    }

    public async override Task<SignInResponse> Handle(SignInRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    { ... }
```

**SignInRequest  class**

```
public class SignInRequest : Request<SignInResponse>
{
    public string? Email { get; set; }
}
```

**SignInResponse class**

```
public class SignInResponse
{
    public bool IsStatus { get; set; }

}
```

**RequestHandler class**

```
public abstract class RequestHandler<T, TResult> : IRequestHandler<T, TResult> where T : IRequest<TResult>
{
    internal readonly DataContext _dataContext;

    public RequestHandler(DataContext dataContext)
    {
        _dataContext = dataContext;
    }

    public abstract Task<TResult> Handle(T request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

**Request class**

```
public abstract class Request<T> : IRequest<T> 
{

}
```

Comment: is `SignInRequestHandler` in the "MyApp.Features" namespace?

Comment: yes it is. All 3 handler, request and response are in the same namespace

Comment: if you are using asp.net 6 you need to add `var app = builder.Build();` after `builder.Host.ConfigureContainer`. The registration looks correct, but I don't think you are actually doing it.

Comment: Yes. I am using .Net 6. and I have used var app = builder.Build(); in my code. Still no luck. help.

Comment: When I try to register individual Handlers from the program.cs it works. builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(SignInRequestHandler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

But, I want to add it via AutoFac.

Comment: My take is that you're are not actually calling `MyMediatorModule` because  when I register types using namespace i usually hace to write something like `.Where(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.Contains("MyApp.Features"))` or I get a NPE. Put a breaking point in the `Load` method and see if it actually gets there

Comment: It does. the exception is thrown at `    return t => c.Resolve(t);
`